# SVG rotating and scaling: How to change the rotation/scaling center?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm using Raphael.js to rotate and scale images. And I know (hope I'm not mistaking) that by default, the *pivot point* for rotations AND scaling, is one and the same with the image center.
How can I change the position of the pivot point so that all future transformations will take place in regard to it?

In other words, how can I modify the rotation/scaling center so that method calls such as `image.transform("s2,5r20")` will work in relation to that point and not the default point?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I've always found it necessary to manually specify the pivot point for the behavior you're describing.

Given an element `el`, use the optional 3rd and 4th parameters to the scale directive to specify the point to scale around:

```
var bbox = el.getBBox();
el.transform( [ "S", "2.0", "2.0", bbox.x + bbox.width / 2, bbox.y + bbox.height / 2 ] );
```

Similarly, for the rotate directive, use the optional 2nd and 3rd parameters for the same purpose:

```
var bbox = el.getBBox();
el.transform( [ "R", 45, bbox.x + bbox.width / 2, bbox.y + bbox.height / 2 ] );
```

Obviously, it's desirable to wrap this functionality into a utility function or Raphael extension.  But this will enable you to achieve the goal you're seeking.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has the [example](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform):

```
ar el = paper.rect(10, 20, 300, 200);
// translate 100, 100, rotate 45°, translate -100, 0
el.transform("t100,100r45t-100,0");
```

Comment: I can't say that I see how this answer applies to my question. Please explain.

Comment: you move the center of the coordinates to the point around which you want to rotate, rotate and then move back, e.g. t10,10r45t-10,-10